# Skip items in bash when in exclusion array

Tags: bash

I have a script that loops over database names and if the name of the current database is in my exclusion array I want to skip it. How would I accomplish this in bash?

```
excluded_databases=("template1" "template0")

for database in $databases
do
  if ...; then
    # perform something on the database...
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by testing each name in turn, but you might be better off filtering the list in one operation. (The following assumes that no name in `$databases` contains whitespace, which is implicit given your `for` loop).

```
for database in $(printf %s\\n $databases |
                  grep -Fvx "${excluded_databases[@]/#/-e}"); do
  # something
done
```

Explanation of the idioms:

1. `printf %s\\n ...` prints each of its arguments on a single line.
2. `grep -Fvx` searchs for exact matches (`-F`) of the whole line (`-x`) and inverts the match result (`-v`).
3. `"${array[@]/#/-e}"` prepends `-e` to each element of the array `array`, which is useful when you need to provide each element of the array as a (repeated) command-line option to a utility. In this case, the utility is `grep` and the `-e` flag is used to provide a match pattern.

I've been criticized in the past for `printf %s\\n` -- some people prefer `printf '%s\n'` -- but I find the first one easier to type. YMMV.

---

As a comment, it seems like it would be better to make `$databases` an array as well as `$excluded_databases`, which would allow for names including whitespace. The `printf | grep` solution still doesn't allow newlines in names; it's complicated to work around that. If you were to make that change, you'd only need to change the `printf` to `printf %s\\n "${databases[@]}"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this condition to check for presence of an element in an array:

```
if [[ "${excluded_databases[@]/$database}" == "${excluded_databases[@]}" ]]
```

Another option using `case`:

```
case "${excluded_databases[@]}" in *"$database"*) echo "found in array" ;; esac
```

Comment: Assumes no database name is a subset of some other database name but should work otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bash 4 or greater then using an associative array will help you here.

```
declare -A excluded_databases=(["template1"]=1 ["template0"]=1)

for database in $databases
do
    if [ -z "${excluded_databases[$database]}" ]; then
        continue
    fi
    # ... do something with $database
done
```

Comment: In 4.2 or greater, you can also use the new `-v` operator: `if [[ -v excluded_databases[$database] ]]; then`